# Adobe Shockwave Player (not Flash)

Tags: plugin

How can I use Adobe Shockwave Player with Tor? Is there any way to add the plugin? Does it reveal your real IP?
Thanks

Comment: *"Does it reveal your real IP?"* There's no way to know because it's proprietary software, which is one of the reasons why add-ons and extensions are recommended against: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherExtensions

Answer (score 0):

Only via routing **all the traffic** by a separate box through Tor. Any plugin that runs in a separate container is able to bypass the proxy settings